# Обрамить массив

Tags: php

есть массив:

```
   [jcfields] => Array
        (
            [31] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 31
                    [title] => Расположение
                    [name] => checkrasp
                    [checked_out] => 42
                    [checked_out_time] => 2022-10-15 13:21:10
                    [note] => 
                    [state] => 1
                    [access] => 1
                    [created_time] => 2022-10-15 13:21:10
                    [created_user_id] => 42
                    [ordering] => 0
                    [language] => *
                    [fieldparams] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
                        (
                            [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [options] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [options0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Панорамные окна
                                                    [value] => Панорамные окна
                                                )

                                            [options1] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Элитная недвижимость
                                                    [value] => Элитная недвижимость
                                                )

                                            [options2] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Проведено электричество
                                                    [value] => Проведено электричество
                                                )

                                            [options4] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Терраса
                                                    [value] => Терраса
                                                )

                                            [options3] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Премиум класс
                                                    [value] => Премиум класс
                                                )

                                            [options8] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Подведена дорога
                                                    [value] => Подведена дорога
                                                )

                                            [options7] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [name] => С отделкой
                                                    [value] => С отделкой
                                                )

                                            [options6] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Новое строительство
                                                    [value] => Новое строительство
                                                )

                                            [options5] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Хорошее состояние
                                                    [value] => Хорошее состояние
                                                )

                                            [options9] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Проведена вода
                                                    [value] => Проведена вода
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [initialized:protected] => 1
                            [separator] => .
                        )

                    [params] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
                        (
                            [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [hint] => 
                                    [class] => 
                                    [label_class] => 
                                    [show_on] => 
                                    [render_class] => 
                                    [value_render_class] => 
                                    [showlabel] => 1
                                    [label_render_class] => 
                                    [display] => 2
                                    [layout] => 
                                    [display_readonly] => 2
                                    [rules] => 
                                )

                            [initialized:protected] => 1
                            [separator] => .
                        )

                    [type] => checkboxes
                    [default_value] => 
                    [context] => com_content.article
                    [group_id] => 5
                    [label] => Расположение
                    [description] => 
                    [required] => 0
                    [language_title] => 
                    [language_image] => 
                    [editor] => Super User
                    [access_level] => Public
                    [author_name] => Super User
                    [group_title] => Инфраструктура
                    [group_access] => 1
                    [group_state] => 1
                    [group_note] => 
                    [value] => Элитная недвижимость, Терраса, Подведена дорога, С отделкой
                    [rawvalue] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Элитная недвижимость
                            [1] => Терраса
                            [2] => Подведена дорога
                            [3] => С отделкой
                        )

                )
```

Подскажите, как можно вывести значения с обрамлением в li, т.е. чтобы получилось примерно так:

```
<ul>
<li> Элитная недвижимость </li>
<li> Терраса </li>
<li> Подведена дорога </li>
<li> С отделкой </li>
</ul>
```

Массив динамический и значений может быть как больше так и меньше. Спасибо.

Comment: А в чём у вас сложность?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не могу разобраться как обернуть каждое значение тегом <li>

Comment: ну как как........ Строка открывающего тега  - Значение - Строка закрывающего тега....... А до и после цикла соответственно теги открыти и закрытия ul ........Как же ещё

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался

```
<?php
   
$lastinfra = ($this->item->jcfields[31]->rawvalue);
   
  foreach ($lastinfra as $value) {
    echo '<li>'. $value . '</li>';
  }
 
?>
```

Comment: Не забудьте по ul и /ul